# Grails create downloadable file

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, download

I call the following jQuery function in my view:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: '${request.contextPath + '/Ticket/passAll'}',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: Data,

                    success: function(result) {


                        $('#export_form').submit();
                    }


                });
```

In a controller I am doing some filtering and formatting of a passed data and and in the end of a method I'm putting that data in a session:

```
session["export"] = filteredData
render "success"
```

If success, $.ajax() submits export_form form that just calls another function in controller that sets up data for download as attachment.

```
    def filter = session["export"].toString()

    def tickets = Ticket.findAll("from Ticket as t ${filter}", [])
    session["export"] = null

    OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(0xEF);
    outputStream.write(0xBB);
    outputStream.write(0xBF);

    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=tickets.csv")
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel:UTF-8")


    def outs = response.outputStream
    def cols = [:]

    outs << "TicketNo;Ticket Details\n"

    tickets.each() {        
        outs << it.ticketNo + ";" + it.ticketDetails

        outs << "\n"

    }

    outs.flush()
    outs.close()
```

This is working in development but when I deployed it on Tomcat I've got the following errror:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.GroovyPageView.createGroovyPageException(GroovyPageView.java:205)
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.GroovyPageView.handleException(GroovyPageView.java:181)
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.GroovyPageView.renderWithTemplateEngine(GroovyPageView.java:152)
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.GroovyPageView.renderMergedOutputModel(GroovyPageView.java:83)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.SpringMVCViewDecorator.render(SpringMVCViewDecorator.java:67)
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.SpringMVCViewDecorator.render(SpringMVCViewDecorator.java:52)
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.doFilter(GrailsPageFilter.java:160)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:119)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:40)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:79)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:65)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    gsp_helpdesk_layoutsmain_gsp.run(gsp_helpdesk_layoutsmain_gsp.groovy:47)
```

EDIT: I'm using jQuery DataTables and Twitter Bootstrap plugins on the page. Table and button that calls the export action are both inside the `<g:uploadForm>`.

I generate the button inside datables code with this line of code:

```
$("div.additional_filters").html('<g:actionSubmit value="${message(code: "datatables.passAll")}" action="export_test" class="btn btn-primary"/> );
```

What is going on and how to fix this? Thank you.

I'm aware that this is not the proper way but for the moment it had to be done like this so please bear with me.

Comment: It's strange, but exception is throwed at `layouts/main.gsp`, not your controller

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Yes, I've seen that. And I didn't have a clue what's going on. But then I saw the last few lines of stack trace: root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    gsp_helpdesk_layoutsmain_gsp.run(gsp_helpdesk_layoutsmain_gsp.groovy:47) So I'm guessing that's the problem.

Comment: Plese show full source code of this controller method

Comment: @IgorArtamonov I've updated the question though I doubt there is anything of significance in there.

Comment: So, `outs.close()` is the last statement, right? could you put `return null` after that?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov I've tried it and it still doesn't work. I've even did it without Ajax. I am just submiting form and calling regular action. Maybe it erally is something with main.gsp.

Comment: @IgorArtamonov I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery Datatables plugins. Maybe I'm causing some kind of plugin conflict But nothing new - everything worked fine and still does - except export functionality.

Comment: Oh, I got it! you're doing `response.setHeader()` after writes to output. Headers should be first, before writing actual content. Grails thinks that it's `text/html` and tries to render gsp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write all HTTP header before writing to output (it's later to setup content-type after actual content):

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=tickets.csv")
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8")

OutputStream outputStream =  response.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(0xEF);
outputStream.write(0xBB);
outputStream.write(0xBF);
```

As I know, if your content type is 'text/html' (it's default value), then Grails tries to render an gsp view for your action (and fails there).

And your should `return null`

Comment: I did that and now I'm getting this error in Chrome: Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or directory could not be found. What is going on :)

Comment: what HTTP status do you get?

Comment: And the the URL is changed to website root. URL of the page from which I'm calling the action www.mywebsite.domain/controller/action and when I click on Export button it changes to www.mywebsite.domain.

Comment: I've changed content type to response.setContentType("text/csv"). The problem was in the :UTF-8 part. But I need to set encoding to UTF-8. Do you know what is the right sintax for this?

Comment: I don't think that `application/vnd.ms-excel:UTF-8` could be valid. Maybe `application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8`?

Comment: Sorry for the late response Igor. Thanks for the great help!